# Cisco 5506-x dynamic site to site tunnel doesn't works

Tags: cisco-asa, ipsec, tunnel, ike

I am followed  [ASA-to-ASA Dynamic-to-Static IKEv1/IPsec Configuration Example](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/119007-config-asa9x-ike-ipsec-00.html)
 step by step, currently I am using IP address 10.0.0.1 for the static peer and 10.0.0.2 for the dynamic peer, but seems the tunnel doesn't works:

[image: topology]

```
ASA1(config)# sh cry ipsec sa 

There are no ipsec sas

ASA1(config)# sh cry isakmp sa 

There are no IKEv1 SAs

There are no IKEv2 SAs

ASA2(config)# sh cry ipsec sa 

There are no ipsec sas

ASA2(config)# sh cry isakmp sa 

There are no IKEv1 SAs

There are no IKEv2 SAs
```

Configuration of ASA1:

```
hostname ASA1  
names  

!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/1  
 nameif outside  
 security-level 0  
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0  
 no shutdown  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/2  
 nameif inside  
 security-level 100  
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0  
 no shutdown  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/3  
 shutdown  
 no nameif      
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/4  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/5  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/6  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/7  
 shutdown  
 no nameif      
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/8  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface Management1/1  
 management-only  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
ftp mode passive  
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface  
object network 192.168.2.0-remote_network  
 subnet 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0  
object network 192.168.0.0-inside_network  
 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0  
object network obj_any  
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0  
access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip any any   
access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip object 192.168.0.0-inside_network object 192.168.2.0-remote_network   
access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit icmp object 192.168.0.0-inside_network object 192.168.2.0-remote_network   
access-list internet_access extended permit ip object 192.168.0.0-inside_network any   
pager lines 24  
mtu outside 1500  
mtu inside 1500  
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1  
no asdm history enable  
arp timeout 14400  
no arp permit-nonconnected  
arp rate-limit 16384  
nat (inside,outside) source static 192.168.0.0-inside_network 192.168.0.0-inside_network destination static 192.168.2.0-remote_network 192.168.2.0-remote_network no-proxy-arp route-lookup  
!  
object network obj_any  
 nat (any,outside) dynamic interface  
!  
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface  
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside  
timeout xlate 3:00:00  
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30  
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02  
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00  
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00  
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute  
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00  
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00  
timeout conn-holddown 0:00:15  
timeout igp stale-route 0:01:10  
user-identity default-domain LOCAL  
aaa authentication login-history  
no snmp-server location  
no snmp-server contact  
service sw-reset-button  
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set tset esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac   
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite  
crypto dynamic-map outside_dyn_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set tset  
crypto dynamic-map outside_dyn_map 1 set reverse-route  
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic outside_dyn_map  
crypto map outside_map interface outside  
crypto ca trustpool policy  
crypto ikev1 enable outside  
crypto ikev1 policy 10  
 authentication pre-share  
 encryption aes-256  
 hash sha  
 group 2  
 lifetime 86400  
telnet timeout 5  
ssh stricthostkeycheck  
ssh timeout 5  
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1  
console timeout 0  

threat-detection basic-threat  
threat-detection statistics access-list  
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept  
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy  
tunnel-group DefaultL2LGroup ipsec-attributes  
 ikev1 pre-shared-key cisco123  
!  
class-map inspection_default  
 match default-inspection-traffic  
!  
!  
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map  
 parameters  
  message-length maximum client auto  
  message-length maximum 512  
  no tcp-inspection  
policy-map global_policy  
 class inspection_default  
  inspect dns preset_dns_map   
  inspect ftp   
  inspect h323 h225   
  inspect h323 ras   
  inspect rsh   
  inspect rtsp   
  inspect esmtp   
  inspect sqlnet   
  inspect skinny    
  inspect sunrpc   
  inspect xdmcp   
  inspect sip    
  inspect netbios   
  inspect tftp   
  inspect ip-options   
!  
service-policy global_policy global  
prompt hostname context   
no call-home reporting anonymous
```

Configuration of ASA2:

```
hostname ASA2  
names  

!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/1  
 nameif outside  
 security-level 0  
 ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0  
 no shutdown  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/2  
 nameif inside  
 security-level 100  
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0  
 no shutdown  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/3  
 shutdown  
 no nameif      
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/4  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/5  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/6  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/7  
 shutdown  
 no nameif      
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface GigabitEthernet1/8  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
interface Management1/1  
 management-only  
 shutdown  
 no nameif  
 no security-level  
 no ip address  
!  
ftp mode passive  
object network 192.168.2.0-inside_network  
 subnet 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0  
object network 192.168.0.0-remote_network  
 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0  
object network obj_any  
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0  
access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip object 192.168.2.0-inside_network object 192.168.0.0-remote_network      
pager lines 24  
mtu outside 1500  
mtu inside 1500  
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1  
no asdm history enable  
arp timeout 14400  
no arp permit-nonconnected  
arp rate-limit 16384  
nat (inside,outside) source static 192.168.2.0-inside_network 192.168.2.0-inside_network destination static 192.168.0.0-remote_network 192.168.0.0-remote_network no-proxy-arp route-lookup  
!  
object network obj_any  
 nat (any,outside) dynamic interface  
!  
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface  
timeout xlate 3:00:00  
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30  
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02  
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00  
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00  
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute  
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00  
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00  
timeout conn-holddown 0:00:15  
timeout igp stale-route 0:01:10  
user-identity default-domain LOCAL  
aaa authentication login-history  
no snmp-server location  
no snmp-server contact  
service sw-reset-button  
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac   
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite  
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_cryptomap  
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 10.0.0.1   
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA  
crypto map outside_map interface outside  
crypto ca trustpool policy  
crypto ikev1 enable outside  
crypto ikev1 policy 10  
 authentication pre-share  
 encryption aes-256  
 hash sha  
 group 2  
 lifetime 86400  
telnet timeout 5  
ssh stricthostkeycheck  
ssh timeout 5  
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1  
console timeout 0  

threat-detection basic-threat  
threat-detection statistics access-list  
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept  
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy  
tunnel-group 10.0.0.1 type ipsec-l2l  
tunnel-group 10.0.0.1 ipsec-attributes  
 ikev1 pre-shared-key cisco123  
!  
class-map inspection_default  
 match default-inspection-traffic  
!  
!  
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map  
 parameters  
  message-length maximum client auto  
  message-length maximum 512  
  no tcp-inspection  
policy-map global_policy  
 class inspection_default  
  inspect dns preset_dns_map   
  inspect ftp   
  inspect h323 h225   
  inspect h323 ras   
  inspect rsh   
  inspect rtsp   
  inspect esmtp   
  inspect sqlnet   
  inspect skinny    
  inspect sunrpc   
  inspect xdmcp   
  inspect sip    
  inspect netbios   
  inspect tftp   
  inspect ip-options   
!  
service-policy global_policy global  
prompt hostname context
```

Any ideas?

packet-tracer result:

```
ASA2(config)# packet-tracer input inside tcp 192.168.2.100 56789 192.168.0.100 443

Result:
input-interface: inside
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
Action: drop
Drop-reason: (no-route) No route to host
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ASA2 (dynamic peer), you did not set the VPN peer - 10.0.0.1 in your `crypto map outside_map 1`.

Please try the followings on ASA2:

- Remove `crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs`
- Add `crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 10.0.0.1`

In addition, on ASA2, you may need to create an interface access-list on inside interface for traffic from ASA2 inside network to reach ASA1 network/subnet at the other end of VPN tunnel.

With dynamic Site-to-Site IPSec VPN, you can initiate the traffic ONLY from dynamic site. Therefore, you need to generate traffic from ASA2 to bring up the tunnel.

If it still does not work, run the packet-tracer command (using CLI) on ASA2 as below and update your question with the output. I will check and update my answer accordingly:

- `packet-tracer input inside tcp 192.168.2.100 56789 192.168.0.100 443`

#### Updated answer:

The output of packet-tracer told us that ASA2 did not know where to route/forward the traffic to ASA1 inside network (192.168.0.100 in 192.168.0.0/24) because it does not have anything in its routing table.

Please add the followings for testing purposes in this particular setup/lab, then try packet-tracer (and ping) again few times:

- On ASA2: `route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1`
- On ASA1: `route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.2`

In this setup/lab, ASA2 is not an actual dynamic peer as you have static IP address configured on outside interface. therefore, you need a static default route on ASA2, and the same on ASA1.

In the real world/scenario, when ASA2 is a dynamic peer (dynamic IP address on outside interface), ASA2 will/should have its own default route thanks to the command `ip address dhcp setroute` or `ip address pppoe setroute`.

---

I hope it is helpful and you can solve the issue.

Comment: you should join us at the [chat] :D

Comment: @Cown Yes, my pleasure!

Comment: Hello Hung, thanks for your quick answer, I have update the configuration on ASA2 but still not works, I have added the result of packet-tracer. Could you please also tell me about how to initiate the traffic from dynamic side? I'm trying to ping 192.168.1.1 from a dhcp client 192.168.2.10 under ASA2, is this a way to initiate the traffic from ASA2? Thank you!

Comment: @Xcat To generate the traffic from dynamic, you can ping or try to access a host/IP at the other VPN site, do not use Firewall IP. The IP 192.168.1.1 does not belong to ASA1 site, it should be in subnet 192.168.0.0/24. I have updated my answer based on your packet-tracer output.

Comment: @Xcat If it still does not work, please run and copy the output of packet-tracer command again.

Comment: Thank you @HungTran the problem has been solved by using your solution:)